# Stop infinity page in Jssor slider

Tags: jssor

I am doing a mobile app which use the slider function in Jssor.

There are 4 pages and I would like to stop the page flow while it is the end of the page.

i.e. After keep swipe to left, from page1 to page4, while page4 reached, it won't go back to page1.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about setting $Loop option to false?